# Adding an extra column of data at the end of a 2d array in c

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

How can I add data from one array and place it as a column on a pre existing array.

```
example
double array[3][2];
```

when printed:

```
3   2
5   5
7   8
```

and I have another array with other info in it

```
double arrayb[3]={1,1,1};
```

i want to run the for loop and be able to print

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
 for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
  cout << array[i][j];}}
```

and this is what I want to see:

```
    3  2  1
    5  5  1
    7  8  1
```

Comment: Do you just want to print the matrix? Or actually create a 3x3 array for use elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    // You have only two elements in array[i], so the limit should be 2
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        // Leave some whitespace before the next item
        cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    // Now print the element from arrayb
    cout << arrayb[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particularly good reason to flush the stream every iteration, or would be `'\n'` suffice instead of `std::endl;`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin This is likely a console-based stream, so `\n` would flush it as well, so why not `endl`?..

Comment: To be honest, I've decided it's best to avoid `endl` in general. If you want to flush the stream, better to do it explicitly with `std::flush`. If you really only want a new-line, better to use `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the obvious method would be something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
       std::cout << array[i][j] << '\t';
    std::cout << arrayb[i] << '\n';
}
```